# What parent::preDispatch() in preDispatch actually does in Account Controller of magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Many times I see `parent::preDispatch()` or for example `parent::validate()` withing actions / functions of magento.

I don't really understand the concern of that parent calls. Can you explain that please on Account Controller of magento.

Today I was working with Account Controller and need to add new action.

I was overriding preDispatch method, but that override doesn't work until I commented `parent::preDispatch`.

I decided with the solution to replace `parent::preDispatch` code with `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::preDispatch()` but not sure if that right or not.

p.s. One day I was overriding validate method of the payment method, that doesn't work also until I commented parent::validate.

Answer (score 0):

When your controller call and

if you add `preDispatch()` function in your controller file
then, first `preDispatch()` function is called.

In account controller `preDispatch()` function is there you can override that and add `parent::preDispatch();` in last then add your code before `parent::preDispatch();`

Comment: but what parent::preDispatch() is actually does?